# C Program - Don't know why it isn't working

Tags: c

The assignment is to create a program that lets the user enter student names and grades, list the input once all entries have been made, then calculate the average for all grades entered. The program uses structures and loops.

The code I have so far is below. It builds without any errors. However, after I enter the first set of "first name, last name, grade" and hit Enter, the program just sits there with a blinking cursor. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 50

// Structure to hold student names and grades
struct student
{
    char    firstName[MAX_LENGTH];
    char    lastName[MAX_LENGTH];
    int     grade;
};

int main ()
{
int i, j, num_students;
int sum = 0;
int cnt = 0;

// Determine how many students will be entered

printf ("Enter the number of students in your class: \n");
scanf ("%d", num_students);

// Obtain student names and grades
printf ("Enter first name, last name and grade separated by spaces. \n");
printf ("Enter END 0 when done entering information.\n\n");

struct student s[num_students];
for (i = 0; i < num_students; ++i) {

    scanf ("%s %s %d", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName, s[i].grade);

    if(strcmp(s[i].firstName, "END") == 0) {
       break;
    }
}

// List students and grades entered
printf ("\nYou entered: \n");
for (j = 0; j < num_students; ++j){

    if(strcmp(s[j].firstName, "END") == 0){
        break;
    }
    printf("Name: %s %s, Grade: %d\n", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName, s[i].grade);

}
// Calculate average of grades entered
for (i = 0; i < num_students; ++i)
{
    if (strncmp(s[i].firstName, "END", 3) == 0){
        break;
    }
    else {
        sum += s[i].grade;
        ++cnt;
    }
}

printf ("Average of Grades: %f\n", (float)sum/cnt);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Grab a [rubber duck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106683/) and patiently explain to it what the computer will do as it runs your program.

Comment: You should check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure that it got 3 fields converted.  You could also print out each set of data as it is read (for debugging) so as to ensure that you're reading what you expect.  It isn't immediately obvious why your code is hanging, though.

Comment: At first glance, I though that you are going to have problems if you terminate the list of names before you reach `MAX_ENTRIES`.  You'll be referencing uninitialized structures in the second and third loops.  However, you keep checking for the name END, so in fact you're OK.  However, it would be more conventional to record `num_students` as the number of records entered, and revise the subsequent loops to go from 0 to less than the number of students.

Comment: `scanf` -> `sscanf` and check return value of `sscanf`

Comment: `Enter END 0` --> `Enter END END 0` .

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
printf("Name: %s %2, Grade: %d\n", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName, &s[i].grade);  
                  ^ Wrong specifier                                  ^ i should be j
```

to

```
printf("Name: %s %s, Grade: %d\n", s[j].firstName, s[j].lastName, s[j].grade);
```

Comment: When I take out the & sign and try to run the program, it stops working and gives me the "... has stopped working" error. :(

Comment: @BrandieKing only at printf, do not scanf.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the '`%2` bug and pass `s[i].grade` not `&s[i].grade`

This works for me: I added a line just after inserting the values for quick feedback

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ENTRIES 20
#define MAX_LENGTH 50

// Structure to hold student names and grades
struct student
{
  char firstName[MAX_LENGTH];
  char lastName[MAX_LENGTH];
  int grade;
};

int
main ()
{
  int i, j;
  int sum = 0;
  int cnt = 0;

  //Obtain student names and grades
  printf ("Enter first name, last name and grade separated by spaces. \n");
  printf ("Enter END 0 when done entering information.\n\n");

  struct student s[MAX_ENTRIES];
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_ENTRIES; ++i)
    {

    scanf ("%s %s %d", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName, &s[i].grade);

    printf ("Name: %s %s, Grade: %d\n", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName,
          s[i].grade);

      if (strcmp (s[i].firstName, "END") == 0)
    {
      break;
    }

    }

  //List students and grades entered
  printf ("\nYou entered: \n");
  for (j = 0; j < MAX_ENTRIES; ++j)
    {

      if (strcmp (s[j].firstName, "END") == 0)
    {
      break;
    }
      printf ("Name: %s %s, Grade: %d\n", s[j].firstName, s[j].lastName,
          s[j].grade);

    }
  //Calculate average of grades entered
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_ENTRIES; ++i)
    {
      if (strncmp (s[i].firstName, "END", 3) == 0)
    {
      break;
    }
      else
    {
      sum += s[i].grade;
      ++cnt;
    }
    }

  printf ("Average of Grades: %f\n", (float) sum / cnt);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line (line no. 42)

```
printf("Name: %s %2, Grade: %d\n", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName, &s[i].grade);
```

to this

```
printf("Name: %s %s, Grade: %d\n", s[j].firstName, s[j].lastName, s[j].grade);
```

I think it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Append the code as , 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 50

// Structure to hold student names and grades
struct student
{
    char    firstName[MAX_LENGTH];
    char    lastName[MAX_LENGTH];
    int     grade;
};

int main ()
{
int i, j, num_students;
int sum = 0;
int cnt = 0;

// Determine how many students will be entered

printf ("Enter the number of students in your class: \n");
scanf ("%d", &num_students);

// Obtain student names and grades
printf ("Enter first name, last name and grade separated by spaces. \n");
printf ("Enter END 0 when done entering information.\n\n");

struct student s[num_students];
for (i = 0; i < num_students; ++i) {

    scanf ("%s %s %d", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName, &s[i].grade);

    if(strcmp(s[i].firstName, "END") == 0) {
       break;
    }
}

// List students and grades entered
printf ("\nYou entered: \n");
for (j = 0; j < num_students; ++j){

    if(strcmp(s[j].firstName, "END") == 0){
        break;
    }
    printf("Name: %s %s, Grade: %d\n", s[j].firstName, s[j].lastName, s[j].grade);

}
// Calculate average of grades entered
for (i = 0; i < num_students; ++i)
{
    if (strncmp(s[i].firstName, "END", 3) == 0){
        break;
    }
    else {
        sum += s[i].grade;
        ++cnt;
    }
}

printf ("Average of Grades: %f\n", (float)sum/cnt);

return 0;

}

Appended line 23 scanf ("%d", &num_students);
         line 32 scanf ("%s %s %d", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName, &s[i].grade);
         line 46 printf("Name: %s %s, Grade: %d\n", s[j].firstName, s[j].lastName, s[j].grade);
```

Answer (score 0):

Missed address operator in scanf argument twice:

```
scanf( "%d", &num_students );
/* .. */
    scanf( "%s %s %d", s[i].firstName, s[i].lastName, & s[i].grade );
```

And index of previous loop was used instead of actual at printing array:

```
printf("Name: %s %s, Grade: %d\n", s[j].firstName, s[j].lastName, s[j].grade);
```

Handling "END"s is unneccessary when prompting for num_students. Just a suggestion: even loop variable names should be longer than a character. And feel free using double at floating point division unless you miss FPU.